# Sitemap content not being displayed by browser php/xml

Tags: php, xml, dynamic, sitemap

trying to create a sitemap.

Page does not display content, however viewsource shows content is there.

I used php to create the sitemap and set up a htaccess rewrite rule.

http://finaldiscounts.com/xml-sitemap.xml

can anyone tell me why this is happening?

i'm having trouble pasting code here... so i saved it in txt file

http://finaldiscounts.com/xml-sitemap.txt

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: you seem to have some errors in your code. can you show us your code or at least the lines around the error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download your site map here: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/details-finaldiscounts.7196149.html
and remove the following line

**//created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com**

the problem is may be you deleted the following line(urlset)

```
  <urlset
  xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
  http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

check this links 
[pontikis.net/blog/creating-dynamic-xml-sitemaps-using-php](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/creating-dynamic-xml-sitemaps-using-php)
[programmersarena.com/create-dynamic-sitemap-using-php](http://www.programmersarena.com/create-dynamic-sitemap-using-php/)

Comment: thank you, the sitemap is dynamic.. so i need to make the changes in the php file..  would you happen to know what needs to be edited?

Comment: check this links http://www.pontikis.net/blog/creating-dynamic-xml-sitemaps-using-php and http://www.programmersarena.com/create-dynamic-sitemap-using-php/

Comment: if this answer is usefull to you means please upvote and choose this as answer